# how to add a node in a binary search tree

Tags: python, recursion, tree

I have this 2 function - 1st is creating a node , 2nd is a recursion function that goes through the tree in order to find a placement for a value:

```
def create_node(number=None):
    return {"Number": number, "Right": None, "Left":None}

def insert(number, pointer):
    pointer_number=pointer["number"]

    if pointer_number is none:
        pointer["number"]=number

    elif number > pointer_number:
        if pointer["right"] is none:
            pointer["right"] = create_node(number)
        else:
            insert(number, pointer["right"])
    else:
        if pointer["left"] is none:
            pointer["left"] = create_node(number)
        else:
            insert (number, pointer["left"])
```

Now I've created the root of the tree:

```
root = create_node(5)
```

The problem i face is when i try to add a value to the tree using the insert function. I'm missing something and I don't know how to do it. Please advise ..

Comment: Well, you haven’t capitalized `None`. (I’d also suggest using classes instead of dicts!)

Answer (score 0):

So 2 things

- NoneType is capitalized: `None` (all if's you do in `create_node`)
- Python string comparison is casesensitive, so when you check for `pointer["number"]` value you are not really checking the one you set in the `create_node` method, which it's key is `"Number"`(capital "N"), being the reason it throws `KeyError`. Same for `"right"` and `"left"`.